# How to speed up the "Waiting for resources" step of a triggered build?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

Why does the "Waiting for resources" step during a build takes so long at times?
When I run my build it occasionally will start running and in other cases it will be waiting for resources for quite some time. What is the cause of this?

[image: Waiting for Resources]

Answer (score 2):

Waiting for resources means that your build is queued behind other jobs. If the jobs in front are computationally heavy, your job may have to wait for a long time. Scheduling the build to run at a time when less resource intensive jobs are queued will help. If the jobs in front are computationally heavy, your job may have to wait for a long time.

Comment: there are also cases when builds are asking for far more resources than they actually need, leaving them in the queue for far longer than necessary if smaller spark profiles had been requested.